# how to remove required field in lastname in magento2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

I want remove validation for lastname in customer address.
i'm removed validation class using override the module.and also change in customer_address_entity table.
      But `"Lastname is required field"` in this error displayed in customer address page.How to overcome this error. If anyone knows Please help me

Comment: remove this data-validate="{required:true,}

Comment: already removed ..but  it will throw  error

Comment: Make Sure you are editing correct file

Comment: module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml.I can able submit an account  without given lastname.but can't able to submit customer address form.it throw last name is requied field.if there is any db table for customer address

Comment: in your eav_attribute table check last name field is_required make it zero make sure take database backup

Comment: already changed it.

Comment: I saw it have two field in same table make sure change two place itself

Comment: yes.i have changed in these two places for lastname using this query UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'.

Comment: Then sorry no idea

Comment: if there is any another table contains last name field validation?

Comment: Please review this: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/How-to-disable-required-field-Last-Name/td-p/69381